# Get the article's view times using Vue.js and Laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5.3

My thought process:

1. When the show page opens, get the article's id with JavaScript.
2. Check this id exist or not in cookie

   1. If not exists, write it into cookie and send an ajax request, the backend updates view times.
   2. If exists, do nothing.

#### Demo:

**View：**

```
<div class="card">
     <div class="card-block text-xs-center">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{$article->title}}</h5>
          <hr class="m-y-2">
          <h6 class="card-subtitle text-muted">date：{{$article->created_at->format('Y-m-d')}}
                            　　　　views：{{$article->view_times}}</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="card-block">
           <p class="card-text">{{$article->content}}</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

**Controller：**

```
class ArticlesController extends Controller
{

    //`show` method
    public function show($id)
    {
        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
        return view('show', compact('article'));
    }

    //the method of updating view times.
    public function statistics(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('id');
        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
        $view_time=$article->view_time;
        $article->view_time=$view_time+1;
        $article->save();
    }

}
```

**JavaScript：**

```
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf-token]').getAttribute('content')
Vue.http.options.emulateJSON = true;

var vm = new Vue({
    el: "body",
    data: function(){
        return{
            id:[]
        }
    },
    created() {


        //1、Get the article's id.Do I have to send an ajax request? Is there any other way?

        this.$http.get('article/get-id').then((response) => {
            // success callback
            this.id=response.data;
        }, (response) => {
            // error callback
        });



        //2、After Getting the `id`，check it in cookie,I don't know how to do it?




        //3、If not exists,write it into cookie and send an ajax request,how to write the if() sentence?

        if(){

            var formData = new FormData();
            var id=this.id;
            formData.append('id',id);

            this.$http.patch('article/statistics', formData,{
                before(request) {
                    if (this.previousRequest) {
                        this.previousRequest.abort();
                    }
                    this.previousRequest = request;
                }
            }).then((response) => {
                // success callback
            }, (response) => {
                // error callback
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Questions:**

There are three questions, shown as comments in JavaScript code above.